# Sum sublevel calculations in DAX - Power Pivot

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I have two levels of calculations: Region (upper level) and City (lower level).

```
|    DATE_1    |    REGION_1    |    city_1    |    1560    |
|    DATE_2    |    REGION_1    |    city_2    |    1234    |
|    DATE_2    |    REGION_1    |    city_3    |    245     |
|    DATE_3    |    REGION_1    |    city_2    |    2345    |
|    DATE_2    |    REGION_1    |    city_1    |    654     |
```

On lower city level i use formula to calculate statistical sample size based on total orders made in a city.

On upper Regional level i DO NOT need to calculate the formula (sample size) i just need to sum the calculations from lower level.

Expected output:

```
|    Region    |    1119    |
|    city_1    |    384     |
|    city_2    |    370     |
|    city_3    |    365     |
```

So in Pivot table i SUM sales for each City and then based on total sales in that city i calculate Statistically significant sample size.

But on Regional level in pivot table i need to SUM those Sample sizes.

I tried using SUMX but results dont work fine (i guess i m not fully getting the sense on SUMX).

Also i feel like using GROUPBY (or some other way to precompile table) and then SUMMING the results from lower level.

Comment: Provide sample data and your expected output in proper tabular format.

Comment: Thanks for updating the sample data. Did you tried with Matrix visual? I think that will be the best match for your presentation. One single measure with SUM should be sufficient for your purpose.

Comment: Sadly i have to implement the solution in Excel )))

Comment: You should have the same options available in Excel. But I have no detail knowledge on Excel :(